# Kafka-pyspark Streaming: KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to subscribe to a Kafka topic through pyspark with the following code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark Structured Streaming from Kafka").getOrCreate()

lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("kafka.partition.assignment.strategy","range").option("subscribe", "test-events").load()

words = lines.select(explode(split(lines.value, " ")).alias("word"))

wordCounts = words.groupBy("word").count()

query = wordCounts.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

and using the following command:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 test_events.py
```

and versions for spark, kafka, java and scala:

```
spark=2.4.0
kafka=2.12-2.3.0
scala=2.11.12
openJDK=1.8.0_221
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Aggregate [word#26], [word#26, count(1) AS count#30L]
+- Project [word#26]
   +- Generate explode(split(cast(value#8 as string),  )), false, [word#26]
      +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[test-events]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:629)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:610)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.consumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchLatestOffsets$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchLatestOffsets$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaOffsetReader$$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaOffsetReader$$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaOffsetReader$$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaOffsetReader$$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchLatestOffsets$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader$$anonfun$fetchLatestOffsets$1.apply(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.runUninterruptibly(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader$$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1.apply(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader$$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1.apply(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:190)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaMicroBatchReader$$initialPartitionOffsets$lzycompute(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$KafkaMicroBatchReader$$initialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchReader.setOffsetRange(KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:341)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: range ClassNotFoundException exception occurred
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:425)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:400)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:772)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: range
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:337)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:423)
    ... 53 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: 'Failed to construct kafka consumer\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = 671c0c25-2f29-49f9-8698-c59a89626da7, runId = 37b4d397-4338-4416-a521-384c8853e99b]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nAggregate [word#26], [word#26, count(1) AS count#30L]\n+- Project [word#26]\n   +- Generate explode(split(cast(value#8 as string),  )), false, [word#26]\n      +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[test-events]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]\n'
2020-02-07 10:03:38 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hoo
```

There are multiple similar questions online but no answer has worked for me so far.
I have also tried the above with spark 2.4.4 with the following:
`spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4 test_events.py` 
but I keep getting the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be drawn when you provide a faulty value for kafka.bootstrap.servers.   This could be a non-existent broker/port, or even a broker list in list form, as opposed to string form.   Meaning, ["broker1:9092", "broker2:9092"] instead of "broker1:9092,broker2:9092".

Depending on where you are running the code, the true cause of the error can be hidden, as well.

Here's the error in Jupyter

```
StreamingQueryException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 39eb0e9d-9487-4838-9d15-241645a04cb6, runId = 763acdcb-bc05-4428-87e1-7b56ae736423]
Current Committed Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[fd]]: {"fd":{"2":4088,"1":4219,"0":4225}}}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[fd]]: {"fd":{"2":4088,"1":4219,"0":4225}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource     org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaStreamingWrite@457e8cfa
+- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13],     org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@2b34a4    79, KafkaV2[Subscribe[fd]]
```

No mention of any problems with the broker list... Now here's the same error via spark-submit:

```
2021-08-13 20:30:44,377 WARN kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Error in attempt 3 getting Kafka offsets: 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:632)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:613)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:533)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:578)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:577)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThreadRunner.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThreadRunner.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.partitionsAssignedToConsumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:531)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:311)
at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.latestOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:394)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:385)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:128)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:382)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:613)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:378)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:211)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:334)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:317)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
```

Important part!

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: ['192.168.1.162:9092'
at         org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59)
at     org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:734)
... 41 more
```

Change kafka.bootstrap.servers from ["192.168.1.162:9092","192.168.1.161:9092","192.168.1.160:9092"] to "192.168.1.162:9092,192.168.1.161:9092,192.168.1.160:9092" and all is well.

Confirm by using kafkacat to ensure that your broker is where you are saying it is.

e.g. `kafkacat -C -b 192.168.1.162:9092,192.168.1.161:9092 -t fd`

Version Info:

- Spark 3.1.2
- PySpark 3.1.1
- Key .jars:

  `sparkSesh = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/username/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,/home/username/jars/commons-pool2-2.11.0.jar")\ .appName("Kafka to Stream") \ .master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `kafka.partition.assignment.strategy` to `roundrobin` from range and see if it works.

```
lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("kafka.partition.assignment.strategy","roundrobin").option("subscribe", "test-events").load()
```

If it doesnt works even after that then try adding `kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar` while submitting the spark job.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 --jars local:///root/sources/jars/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar --driver-class-path local:///root/sources/jars/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar test_events.py
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Tried both and still getting the saem error.

Comment: I would suggest using a newer kafka clients of 0.10.2 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

kafka version 2.12-2.2.0
spark 2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
scala 2.11.12

Comment: You need to use Scala 2.12 with those

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: range

Unless you explicitly need the assignment strategy, then remove the option.

Otherwise, it must be the fully qualified Java class name